# How do I load a file with a bunch of descriptions for objects into an array?

Tags: java, arrays, file, bufferedreader

I am currently trying to code my own Magic Item Generator for personal use. Right now I am stuck on trying to load a bunch of spell and object descriptions into arrays that will be called from an array if the spell/object is rolled into the magic items creation.

I am currently stuck trying to load multiple descriptions into an array. I can only seem to put one description into the array before it just quits.

Currently I have this code:

```
public class LoadDescription {
public static ArrayList<String> descriptions = new ArrayList<String>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File filename = new File("spellconcept.txt");
    loadDescriptions(filename);

    System.out.println(descriptions.get(0));
    // System.out.println(descriptions.get(1));

}

public static void loadDescriptions(File name) throws IOException {
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(name);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int i = 0;

    while (!br.readLine().equals("@@@")) {

        try {
            String line = br.readLine();
            while (!line.isEmpty()) {
                sb.append(" " + line);
                line = br.readLine();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        ;

        descriptions.add(sb.toString());
    }
    i++;
}}
```

This is the text file I am trying to use. Please ignore the lack of intelligence in it, it's just a test file:

```
   @This is a description of a spell.
   I often wonder how often I can write
   the word often.Without seeming that it is too often that I write this out. 
   Does it not seem weird. The quick brown fox jumps over the small red fence.

    @This is another description of a spell


    @Maybe add another line here, \n see if this works? maybe?


    @@@
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**here is the modified code:**

### **sample file:**

@This is a description of a spell.

I often wonder how often I can write the word often.Without seeming that it is too often that I write this out. 
Does it not seem weird. The quick brown fox jumps over the small red fence.

@This is another description of a spell

Apple is fruit.
It is red in colour.

@3rd description

I have a pet.
Its a dog named john.

@@@

```
public static ArrayList<String> descriptions = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        File filename = new File("C:\\temp\\test.txt");
        loadDescriptions(filename);


        System.out.println("*************");
    for(String ln:descriptions){
        System.out.println(ln);
    }

    }

    public static void loadDescriptions(File name) throws IOException {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(name);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int i = 0;
        String line=null;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null ) {

            if(line.startsWith("@")){
                if(i>0){
                 descriptions.add(sb.toString());
                 sb = new StringBuilder();
                }

            }else{
               if(!line.isEmpty()){
                System.out.println(line);
                sb.append(" " + line);
              }
            }


            i++;

        }

    }
```

Comment: What does the System.out.println("*****************"); do in this case?  Everything else makes sense but that.

Comment: just ignore it..it just to print a line to mark the beginning of the array printing

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your loop,

```
   while (!br.readLine().equals("@@@")) {
```

you call `readLine()`, consuming the 1-liner lines, but you don't capture the line itself to process it.

Comment: How would you recommend fixing this then? I am at a loss of what other methods I could use.